# svn:externals help (TortoiseSVN 1.7.6)

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

I have a directory

```
D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace\MF_CENTER_INFO
```

`SVN_HOME` - is a root svn working folder

`MF_CENTER_INFO` - the folder which I want to be commited to another svn repository

The default repository for `D:\SVN_HOME\` is `svn://10.101.101.101/svn/ee/trunk`
but `MF_CENTER_INFO` has to be commit to `svn://10.101.101.101/svn/mf-center-vp/`  (**IPs are same**)

so, what I did:

right mouse click on `D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace\`

added property
[image]

but when I choose commit or view properties for `D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace\MF_CENTER_INFO` it shows default rep, now the external one

[image]

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that **svn:externals** property is set incorrectly: the value should be

```
MF_CENTER_INFO <url>
```

Please check [Setting Up Subversion Externals With TortoiseSVN](http://justaddwater.dk/2007/10/23/setting-up-subversion-externals-with-tortoisesvn/)

Comment: Is MF_CENTER_INFO under version control? I.e. is svn://10.101.101.101/svn/ee/trunk/MF_CENTER_INFO exists in svn repo?

Comment: it exists in: svn://10.101.101.101/svn/ee/trunk/EclipseWorkspace/MF_CENTER_INFO

Comment: Then, if you have already moved it to svn://10.101.101.101/svn/mf-center-vp/ - have you deleted svn://10.101.101.101/svn/ee/trunk/EclipseWorkspace/MF_CENTER_INFO ? Or do you need to keep both?

Comment: I didn't delete it and I don't need it. Should I delete it from svn://10.101.101.101/svn/ee/trunk/EclipseWorkspace/MF_CENTER_INFO and how? Thank you

Comment: You can't have externals with the same name as folder in svn repo: so, you can 1) delete it with svn del 2) rename with svn move (see also http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html) or 3) correct SVN externals:  MF_CENTER_INFO_REMOTE svn://10.101.101.101/svn/mf-center-vp/

Comment: I want to delete it with svn delete, but it says: No write-lock in 'D:\SVN_HOME\EclipseWorkspace' Arghhh

Answer (score 1):

MF_CENTER_INFO must

- not be ignored
- exist in parent only as "virual" folder, not real

Way to fix

- Remove all properies in 1-st commit
- Move|delete physical folder on 2-nd commit
- Create (correct) svn-externals in 3-rd commit